# Add New column not containing value in previous column

Tags: python, pandas

I've seen several solutions to this, but for some reason I just cant get this working.

I have data that looks like this.

```
data = {'Col1': ['Apples', 'Bananna, Pear', 'Suns, Moons, Stars', 'Orange, Blue, Green']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

                  Col1                 Col2
0               Apples               Apples
1        Bananna, Pear        Bananna, Pear
2   Suns, Moons, Stars   Suns, Moons, Stars
3  Orange, Blue, Green  Orange, Blue, Green
```

And I would like it to look like this.

**EDIT:  Explain logic of col2**

The goal is that if `col1` does not have a comma in it (,) then I'd like to add that value to `col2`.  Eventually, I'll fill in the `None` values down with what is in `col2`

```
goal_data = {'Col1': ['Apples', 'Bananna, Pear', 'Suns, Moons, Stars', 'Orange, Blue, Green'],
             'Col2': ['Apples', None, None, None]}

goal_df = pd.DataFrame(goal_data)
                 Col1    Col2
0               Apples  Apples
1        Bananna, Pear    None
2   Suns, Moons, Stars    None
3  Orange, Blue, Green    None
```

I've tried a few variations of this for loop

```
for i in df['Col1']:
    if ',' in i:
        None
    else:
        df['Col2'] = df['Col1']
```

But I keep running into issues where the entire 'col1' is either copied, or everything in `col2` is set to `None` or `Apples`.

In my actual data, I have thousands of rows that repeats this pattern.  When I run different versions of this, it will usually set `col2` to whatever the last `col1` value was that did not have a comma in it.

Comment: Can you explain the logic used to generate `col2`?

Comment: Yes.  I'll add this as an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try:

```
f = lambda x: None if ',' in x else x

df['Col2'] = df['Col1'].apply(f, axis=1)
```

Comment: This worked, but you got it backwards.  If you change your solution to f = lambda x: None if ',' in x else x, i will accept it.

Comment: my bad, glad it helped!